# Is it possible to detect if client supports SNI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, .htaccess, apache-2.4

So my SSL is using SNI, Bing doesn't want to index my site because of that and also some other sites are having problems. Such as reddit.

Is it possible to detect if client supports SNI?

I was thinking something like:

```
if (sni_support)

- force https

else

- http
```

I'm using latest Apache2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Bing isn't really a significant search engine anyway. And with them failing to address this most critical issue for years now, it's unlikely they will ever be significant.

Comment: I have answered a very similar question before: http://serverfault.com/a/586018/214507